# Using Concatenate column in aggregate function for PIVOT in Snowflake

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT *

  from (SELECT Ant, Bird, Cat, Dog, Egg, Fish, Gold, Hen, RANK() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY (Ant|| Bird|| Cat|| Dog|| Egg||Fish) ORDER BY Dog) AS ROW_COUNT
        FROM TABLE1 WHERE Gold = '01')
        
    pivot( MAX(Egg||Fish||Hen) for ROW_COUNT IN (1,  2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,    10)
         ) 
      as QRY
;
```

Basically I would like to make this work in Snowflake, but it did not because Snowflake does not allow me to concatenate columns inside aggregate function. However, I notice that this code could run fine in Oracle DB. Can anyone hele me with this? I tried to create concatenate column before put it in MAX(), but that returned different result from the top one (tested in Oracle DB). For instance,

```
SELECT *

  from (SELECT Ant, Bird, Cat, Dog, Egg, Fish, Gold, Hen, Egg||Fish||Hen AS concat_col ,RANK() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY (Ant|| Bird|| Cat|| Dog|| Egg||Fish) ORDER BY Dog) AS ROW_COUNT
        FROM TABLE1 WHERE Gold = '01')
        
    pivot( MAX(concat_col) for ROW_COUNT IN (1,  2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,    10)
         ) 
      as QRY
;
```

Above show different results that I expected.

Comment: Please provide sample as `CREATE TABLE Table1 AS ...` and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Due to personal reason I could not post the real-code. Anyway, I have found the solution, which simply delete the concatenate columns from select. This prevented the pivot to transpose appropriately.

```
SELECT *

  from (SELECT Ant, Bird, Cat, Dog, Gold, Egg||Fish||Hen AS concat_col ,RANK() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY (Ant|| Bird|| Cat|| Dog|| Egg||Fish) ORDER BY Dog) AS ROW_COUNT
        FROM TABLE1 WHERE Gold = '01')
        
    pivot( MAX(concat_col) for ROW_COUNT IN (1,  2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,    10)
         ) 
      as QRY
;
```